# Filtering DynamoDB Streams events for a specific field change

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm interested in value changes of a specific (numeric) field/column (say "count") of a DynamoDB table.

I know that I could write a Lambda that, once triggered, compares the new image with the old one and then decides whether it is the case of actually doing something or not. But, since my table collects a sort of status updates and only a few of them are actually significant for my trigger, in such a setting, the Lambda would be invoked pointlessly most of the times (and, moreover, I would be charged money for having invoked the Lambda).

So I want to filter the DynamoDB Stream events and, according to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html), it should be possible (even if no example for similar cases is given).

My problem is that I cannot find how to write the equivalent of `OldImage['count'] != NewImage['count']` in the filter pattern.

Here is an example of how this part of my SAM template should appear.

```
CountChangeDetector:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/
      Handler: trigger.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      FunctionName: "CountChangeDetector"
      AutoPublishAlias: live      
      Events:
        Stream:
          Type: DynamoDB
          Properties:
            Stream: !GetAtt MyTable.StreamArn
            BatchSize: 10
            StartingPosition: TRIM_HORIZON
            FilterCriteria:
              Filters:
                - Pattern: '{"OldImage": {"count": [ { "anything-but": [ {"NewImage": {"count"}} ] } ]}}'
```

Of course, the way I've defined the pattern is incorrect and I get an error.

So, how shall the pattern be defined?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you have already found your answer, but still adding for any newbie searching for the same.

Unfortunately the answer is "No". You cannot compare two two fields of the stream data with each other. Because, there is no "numeric not equal" operator available for pattern.

The work around would be writing the logic in the pre-processing of lambda function before calling the handler.

Comment: Yeah, that’s exactly what I did in the end (checking if the count has changed and storing that info as a bool that trigger the trigger), but I’m not completely satisfied with this approach. Is there anything like “string not equal”? If so, I could cast that number to string and still exploit the initial idea…

Comment: What do you mean by *writing the logic in the pre-processing of lambda function*?